# Removing HTML tags from string is not working as expected

Tags: xml, string, t-sql, xhtml, special-characters

I have a function that removes HTML tags from a given XML string like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fGetTextWithoutHtml
(
    @Html XML
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(2000) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2000), @html)
    DECLARE @start INT
    DECLARE @end INT
    DECLARE @length INT

    SET @start = CHARINDEX('<', @text)
    SET @end = CHARINDEX('>', @text, CHARINDEX('<', @text))
    SET @length = (@end - @start) + 1
    WHILE @start > 0 AND @end > 0 AND @length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @text = STUFF(@text, @start, @length, '')
        SET @start = CHARINDEX('<', @text)
        SET @end = CHARINDEX('>', @text, CHARINDEX('<', @text))
        SET @length = (@end - @start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@text))
END
```

The input XML looks like this:

> `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve"> <p>​- This is a string.<br /></p></html>`

The expected output would be:

> "- This is a string."

But when I use my function I get an odd result. If I copy it to an editor, the output looks like this:

> " - This is a string."

If I copy the result directly to SQL Server editor, it gets an additional (wider) hyphen at the beginning:

> " -- This is a string."

How can I get the string without the HTML tags, the additional hyphen and the leading spaces?

### Edit

I tried to find out if there is a non-printable character in my input string:

```
PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2000), @html)
```

The result looked like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve"> &#x20;<p>​- This is a string.<br /></p></html>
```

There is `&#x20` inside my string. But when I changed

```
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@text))
```

to

```
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@text, '&#x20;', '')))
```

the result looked the same (the spaces and the additional hyphen were still there)...

Comment: This is not related to the code in your function, but rather the input (and the way it is converted to/from XML). The problem you describe can be replicated with just the following: `declare @x xml = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve"> <p>​- This is a string.<br /></p></html>' print convert(NVARCHAR(2000),@x)`
it looks like there is a hidden/non-printable character between the `>` of the `<p>` and the `-`

Comment: Thank you @KeithHall. I found out that there is a non-printable character. But I couldn't find out how to remove it. See my edited question.

Comment: @KeithHall Good guess! Your assumption was correct. There was a leading `0x0B20`, which was a *dotted list* sign probably...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pass in your HTML as XML and there is an "xhtml" namespace I'd suggest to read your content with XML methods:

```
DECLARE @x XML = N'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve"> <p>​- This is a string.<br /></p></html>';
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
SELECT Each.node.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS pContent
FROM @x.nodes('/html//*') Each(node)
```

The result looks correct, but there is an unprintable sign before the hyphen (you see this by moving your cursor over this text. There is one position, where your cursor won't move... Now try the same code *without the leading "N"*. Now you get a question mark before the hyphen. This is a **unicode** sign, which is not defined for `VARCHAR`...

Try this code to read your unicode string byte-wise:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SingleBytes(@SomeText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH nr10 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(A)
)
,RunningNumbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@SomeText),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(NULL))) AS Nmbr FROM nr10,nr10 AS a,nr10 AS b,nr10 AS c,nr10 AS d,nr10 AS e,nr10 AS f,nr10 AS g
)
,ByteWise AS
(
    SELECT CAST(CAST(@SomeText AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ByteWiseText
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(ByteWiseText,Nmbr,1) AS TheCharacter
      ,ASCII(SUBSTRING(ByteWiseText,Nmbr,1)) AS ASCII_Code
FROM ByteWise,RunningNumbers;
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.SingleBytes(N'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve"> <p>​- This is a string.<br /></p></html>');
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.SingleBytes;
```

You find, that between the `>` and the `-` there is 11-32, which is [0B20, find details here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0b20/index.htm)

This might be a leading sign of a list?

Anyway: You can define this like this:

```
DECLARE @EvilChar NVARCHAR(1)=CAST(CAST(CHAR(11) + CHAR(32) AS VARBINARY(2)) AS NVARCHAR(1));
```

You can use this variable in a `REPLACE`...

Good luck :-)